# ASP.net weekly schedule control

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, scheduling, custom-server-controls, servercontrols

Can anyone recommend a free asp.net control that I can use for the following:

- Weekdays Monday-Saturday along the top row
- Time of day along left hand side
- Template fields for the actual data
- Databindable
- Cells span the rows based on the start time and end time

Here is a control that I found that is pretty good, but I am trying to find alternatives:
[Databound Schedule controls](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/schedule.aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[DayPilot](http://www.daypilot.org/) is a pretty good general purpose calendaring/schedule control.

The full version is not free, but there is a "lite" version available which is not only free but open source!

Comment: I downloaded day pilot to try. The problem is that it doesn't show weekdays along the top, but actual dates.

Comment: @Ronnie - You can alter the "HeaderDateFormat" and set it to a custom value (i.e. "dddd" for just the Weekday name).  See the "HeaderDateFormat.aspx" file in the "/demo" folder of the DayPilot Lite download.

Comment: @CraigTP - Nice! The only thing that I think it's missing is the template for displaying data. It only takes 1 field: DataTextField property. Is there a way to show more than one piece of data? I am going to try and aggregate the data into some HTML and see what the control does.

Comment: @Ronnie - You should be able to assign some HTML as a string to the DataTextField property as this should display fine within the control. (for example, I tried it with "<h1>Test</h1>" and it displayed the word "Test" in the correct Heading 1 style.  Be careful of space, though.

Comment: @CraigTP - Yes, space ended up being the problem. The cells do not resize vertically to accommodate for the cell content. I ended up using the control that I linked to in the original post. Thanks!

Comment: @Ronnie - The cells will only take up as much vertical space as for the time they're allocated.  I.e. If the calendar "entry" is for 1 hour it will only take up a small amount of vertical space.  Obviously, if it's for 5 hours, it'll take more vertical space.  If it resized for the content, it would

Comment: affect the time that the calendar "entry" is made for (i.e. extend the time for the entry).  However, glad you've found a solution for your problem, and glad to be of some help!