# scheduler like google calendar in MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar, scheduler

I am trying to integrate a calendar plugin like google calendar with custom database and code with asp.net MVC in C#.

It needs to handle Day/Week/Month Events in the Calendar as like google calendar.

I found the similar plugin in jquery http://www.webappers.com/2009/08/04/jquery-weekly-calendar-plugin-inspired-by-google-calendar/. But it shows only the Week

Do anyone have a reference to this? Please suggest

Comment: Does anyone have a sample in MVC for the Calendar like google? I am searching it for a long time and not able to find a matching one.

Comment: You can try DayPilot for MVC: http://mvc.daypilot.org/demo/Calendar/GoogleLike (my product, commercial)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'd try [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/)

Comment: I was trying on that, but there is no time slots in week and day View. Is there any option to do that?

Comment: hello prasad, i am the author of fullcalendar. the newest version, 1.4, has it. hope it works for you

Answer (score 5):

I answered a similar question a while ago, "[ASP.net weekly schedule control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/700810/asp-net-weekly-schedule-control)", and the answer there would still be relevant to yourself.

> [DayPilot](http://www.daypilot.org/) is a pretty good general
>   purpose calendaring/schedule control.
>
> The full version is not free, but
>   there is a "lite" version available
>   which is not only free but open
>   source!

The "lite" version will give you both Day and Week (and "Work" week) views of the calendar and will show a Month Scheduler view.

Whilst the original DayPilot component is not meant for ASP.NET MVC, a guy called Craig Stuntz has adapted the DayPilot Lite component for ASP.NET MVC:

[Using DayPilot with ASP.NET MVC](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/05/12/38297/)

Answer (score 2):

The best one I found is [dhtmlxScheduler](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxScheduler/). It is highly customizable, fires events and works cross-browser. It is free for GPL projects, otherwise there are commercial licenses available with affordable prices. And their customer support is excellent!

Answer (score 1):

Use Google's [Calendar API](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/)

Comment: Google calendar API is all driven by its own google's. But i need to have my own database for the events and custom look of the Event Calendar. 
An excellent control, i saw when searching is http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxScheduler/index.shtml

I need to try for a similar one, with ASP.NET MVC and C# with the help jquery too.

Answer (score 1):

I am using this jquery plugin.
http://www.web-delicious.com/jquery-events-calendar-wdcalendar/
It provide php mvc sample, you can convert it to .net mvc